# Flash and remove my arrow

Tags: ios, swift

After flashing my arrow for x seconds, I want it to disappear automatically. I used [self.arrowImage.slayer removeAllanimations], but it does not work:

```
 @IBAction func answerButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject){

      var score    = scoreField.text?.toInt()
      var question = questionField.text

      // display question
      questionField.text = listOfQuestions[currentQuestionIndex] 

      if (questionField.text == listOfQuestions[9]) {
           if (score >= 7) {
                // move to stage 2
           }

           if (score < 3) {
                arrowImage.hidden = false
                self.arrowImage.alpha = 0;
                UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.2,
                                              options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.Autoreverse,
                                           animations: {
                                              self.arrowImage.alpha = 0.5
                                           },
                                           completion:nil)
           }
           // questions of stage 1 still display
```

Comment: What doesn't work about `[self.arrowImage.layer removeAllanimations]`? (fixed to say `arrowImage.layer`, not `arrowImage.slayer`, which I assume is a typo in your forum post, not in your original code?)

Answer (score 0):

In the completion block of your animation, just set the arrowImage to be hidden.

```
self.arrowImage.hidden = true
```

Comment: @TanguyMP "Don't work." Could you possibly be more vague? (probably not.)

Comment: @Duncan C. it does not work. I tried using self.arrowImage.hidden = true

Comment: @DuncanC The arrow flashes normally, and I want it to disappear after 4 seconds, but it doesn't. I tried to use [self.arrowImage.hidden = true] as Clever Error says.